# CakePHP :: What to return for custom validation method?

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a custom validation rule to make sure that a non-zero price is set in a field.  I have a placeholder (0.00) in the field to keep users from entering things like dollar signs.  When I go to validate for a non-zero entry, however, `$this->data[$this->alias]['price']` is '0.00' in my test, but the validation is working - it invalidates.  But when I put in 1000.00, it's also invalidating.

One thing I can't find is what/how to return from a custom validation field to invalidate the field.  Currently, the code is:

```
public function notZeroPrice($check){
    if ($check == '0.00')
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

The docs aren't clear on the structure of `$check` either.

Answer (score 3):

If it validates, return true. If the doesn't, return false.

However, your validation method is flawed to begin with. `$check` is an array if you debug it, so your method is always going to return false. Secondly, you want to test if its > 0, not just equal to '0.00'. You'll be comparing 2 string so that won't work, either.

Instead, return true if the value is greater than 0 (int). You can get it value out of the array easily by using `array_shift($check)`;

```
return array_shift($check) > 0; // or something similar.
```

You may even get away with `'rule' => array('comparison', '>', 0),` core validation.

(I'm assuming not zero for a price also means not a negative price)